# javascript to change colour of an svg shape

Tags: javascript, svg

Hi is there a way of using javascript for example using buttons to change colour of an svg shape? If so could someone please guide me in the right direction thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have a number of these shapes, then look at the [d3 library](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), which is designed explicitly to allow you to bind data to svg attributes. A good explanation of the way it works is the [Three little circles](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) tutorial.

If you want to just change an attribute of an svg shape on a button click, then you need an onclick handler for the button:

```
function handleClick() {
    // code to modify svg here, e.g.:
    document.getElementById('svgShapeId').setAttribute('cx',150);
}

document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = handleClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using JS to create animation elements to highlight colors based on mouse over/out:
http://phrogz.net/SVG/change-color-on-hover.svg

Here's an example of an SVG that changes lots of colors, and house some silly mouseover buttons:
http://phrogz.net/SVG/rgbhsv.svg

Here's an example that shows SVG in XHTML, with both native HTML widgets (an HTML5 slider) as well as draggable SVG elements (the path handles):
http://phrogz.net/SVG/area_of_path.xhtml

In general:

1. Find elements
2. Attach event handlers
3. In the event handlers, adjust properties (either via setting XML attributes or via the [SVG DOM](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/objects))